# iOS how to wrapper C++ class in Swift project

Tags: ios

I have a static library in C++, and now I want to use this library in my new Swift project. I found that I couldn't use C++ class directly in Swift project, so I have to wrapper this library in OC. Then I have some problem wrapping this:

```
//AbstractClassA.h
#include <string>

class AbstractClassA {
public:
    virtual string getString() = 0;
    virtual int getInt() = 0;
    virtual ~AbstractClassA() {};

};

//AbstractClassB.h
class AbstractClassB {
public:
    virtual void function(int a) = 0;
    virtual ~AbstractClassB() {};

};

//ChildA.h
#include "AbstractClassA.h"
#include "AbstractClassB.h"

class ChildA : public AbstractClassA
{
public:
    ChildA(int a = 640);
    ChildA( AbstractClassB* classb, int a = 640);
    virtual ~ChildA();
    string getString();
    int getInt();

protected:
    int a;
    string b;
};
```

How to wrapper these classes in OC? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create an Objective-C++ class that wraps the C++ class. The header file must not contain any C++ features; the file with the implementation must end in .mm to tell Xcode to use the Objective-C++ compiler, not Objective-C.

In the .h file, you'd have an interface for class ChildAWrapper, methods init, initWithInt:, initWithClassB:, initWithClassB:Int: and readonly properties stringValue and intValue.

In the .mm file, you'd have an instance variable of type ChildA*. The init methods create a ChildA object. dealloc deletes it. You implement the properties by calling the methods of the ChildA object, converting the std::string to an NSString*.

Same for ClassB with an Objective-C class ClassBWrapper. There you want a readonly property void* wrappedClass returning a pointer to the the ClassB object, converted to void*, because ChildAWrapper will need that.

Comment: Sadly this also is my understanding. It's a lot of work.

Comment: Sorry about late, I can't figure out the ClassBWrapper, could you show me the code snippets? And in ChildAWrapper, what method do I actually need? initWithAbstractClassB:  or  initWithAbstractClassBWrapper?